# How to flatten nested series?

Tags: common-lisp

Using [SERIES library from CLTL2 appendix A](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/Groups/AI/html/cltl/clm/node347.html#SECTION003400000000000000000), I want a flat series from nested series. For example:

```
(map-fn t (lambda (x)
            (map-fn t (lambda (y)
                        (cons x y))
                    (scan '(1 2 3))))
        (scan '(4 5 6)))

=> #Z( #Z( (4 . 1) (4 . 2) (4 . 3) )
       #Z( (5 . 1) (5 . 2) (5 . 3) )
       #Z( (6 . 1) (6 . 2) (6 . 3) ) )
```

I want to make this series of series to one series as below:

```
=> #Z( (4 . 1) (4 . 2) (4 . 3)
       (5 . 1) (5 . 2) (5 . 3)
       (6 . 1) (6 . 2) (6 . 3) )
```

If I would have an appropriate series concatenation function, it would be good. Although the series library has CATENATE function, it takes just some series in its &rest parameter. I could

```
(apply #'catenate list-of-series)
```

but it accepts a **list** of series, not series of series. Unfortunately, there are not any functions for folding series, while there are for mapping and filtering.  The PRODUCING macro shown on A.4. Primitives section in CLTL2 does not work for me because it also seems not to flatten a nested loop. I cannot use NEXT-OUT macro in nested situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(apply #'catenate
       (collect (map-fn t (lambda (x)
                            (map-fn t (lambda (y)
                                        (cons x y))
                                    (scan '(1 2 3))))
                        (scan '(4 5 6)))))
```

But that is bit of a cheat. To do it properly in series:

```
(producing (prod) ((zz (generator (map-fn t (lambda (x)
                                              (map-fn t (lambda (y)
                                                          (cons x y))
                                                      (scan '(1 2 3))))
                                          (scan '(4 5 6)))))
                   cur)
           (loop
              (tagbody
               redo
                 (if (null cur)
                     (setq cur (generator (next-in zz (terminate-producing)))))
                 (next-out prod (next-in cur (progn 
                                               (setq cur nil)
                                               (go redo)))))))

=> #Z((4 . 1) (4 . 2) (4 . 3)
      (5 . 1) (5 . 2) (5 . 3)
      (6 . 1) (6 . 2) (6 . 3))
```